# Laravel Project Not Running On Server

Tags: laravel-6, filezilla

I have deployed my laravel project on server. When I hit the url it gives me error but no log is generated in log folder.

```
This page isn’t working
[Domain Name] is currently unable to handle this request.

HTTP ERROR 500
```

I have moved the public folder contents to root directory and edited the index.php.

I checked the permission for storage, vendor and bootstrap folder and they have required permission.

**index.php**

```
<?php

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));


require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';


$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

**Server.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The project is hosted on shared hosting and I've used filezilla to upload it on server. What else I need to do to make it work. This is my first uploading the project on the server.

Comment: Have you configured the direction to public folder ?

Comment: I removed the contents of public folder into the root folder and updated the index.php file accordingly (refer my question)

Comment: Anything in the error log of the server (e.g. apache)?